# Selenium code does not work inside a loop, but works outside the loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just picked up Selenium due to an assigned task. This task is about scraping information from a list of URLs. I have successfully scraped the required information from one of the URL in python, but when I happily put it into a loop that iterates through the list of URLs, it failed. Is there any hint why this would happen? Below shows my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
df = pd.read_csv("URLs.csv")
missing = df[df['input_addresses_x'] == '[nan]']['transaction_id']

for i in missing:
    driver.get("https://explorer.iota.org/mainnet/message/%s" % i)
    l = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[width="5"]')
    print(l)
    print(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.card--header'))
    from_counter = int(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.card--header'[0].text[-1])

    input_addresses = []
    for j in l:
        counter = 1
        print(j.location)
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(j.location['y']+50) + ');')
        j.click()
        tmp = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.margin-r-t')
        for k in tmp: 
            if k.text[0:4] != 'iota' and counter == 1 and from_counter > 0:
                print(k.text)
                input_addresses.append(k.text)
                counter = 0
                from_counter -= 1
            if from_counter == 0:
                driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(j.location['y']+50) + ');')
                j.click()
                from_counter = 1000

    df[df['transaction_id'] == i]['input_addresses_x'] = input_addresses
```

The problem now is that everything works fine until this line:

```
l = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[width="5"]')
```

It cannot find the desired elements even in the very first iteration. But when I run the following block separately on the first element of the Series `missing`, it works perfectly:

```
driver.get("https://explorer.iota.org/mainnet/message/4f7f58df296650a86577fbefea1659d090b0296aacaca8e70e6f80191cf79dbf")
l = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[width="5"]')
print(l)
print(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.card--header'))
from_counter = int(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.card--header'[0].text[-1])

input_addresses = []
for j in l:
    counter = 1
    print(j.location)
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(j.location['y']+50) + ');')
    j.click()
    tmp = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.margin-r-t')
    for k in tmp: 
        if k.text[0:4] != 'iota' and counter == 1 and from_counter > 0:
            print(k.text)
            input_addresses.append(k.text)
            counter = 0
            from_counter -= 1
        if from_counter == 0:
            driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(j.location['y']+50) + ');')
            j.click()
            from_counter = 1000
```

Anybody has any idea on why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As suggest by Himanshu in the comment, I now add a ready-to-go version here for those who might want to test it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://explorer.iota.org/mainnet/message/4f7f58df296650a86577fbefea1659d090b0296aacaca8e70e6f80191cf79dbf")
l = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[width="5"]')
from_counter = int(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.card--header')[0].text[-1])

input_addresses = []
for j in l:
    counter = 1
    print(j.location)
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(j.location['y']+50) + ');')
    j.click()
    tmp = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.margin-r-t')
    for k in tmp:
        if k.text[0:4] != 'iota' and counter == 1 and from_counter > 0:
            print(k.text)
            input_addresses.append(k.text)
            counter = 0
            from_counter -= 1
        if from_counter == 0:
            driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(j.location['y']+50) + ');')
            j.click()
            from_counter = 1000
```

Comment: please minimal reproducible example

Comment: A reproducible snippet is now online:)

Comment: and which line works outside the loop? but not inside?

Comment: This one: `l = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[width="5"]')`

Comment: It cannot locate the desired element, but when I run it on jupyter it works fine

Comment: sometimes browser and JavaScript need time to add new elements - and it may need `time.sleep()`  or some of [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) methods. And sometimes page removes invisible items when user scroll page.

Comment: when I run code  then browser shows page with message `Not found: We could not find any messages, addresses, outputs, milestones or indexes for the query.`. Your address may works only on your browser with your cookies. If you want to search something then better write code whihc opens page with search form and it put searched value in form, and it click button `search`

Comment: Thanks for your advice furas! I will try the waits methods and automated searches to see if they work.